# how to remove accidentally created '~' and '..'

Tags: command-line, wget, command

I'm using wget to download some webpages and I used the `-P` option without knowing that it wouldn't expend `..` or `~`. So I found I've created them after running the program. Now the problem is, how do I safely remove them? I can't use `rm` because it treats them as the parent directory and the home directory.

Comment: You mean you have created **files** called `~` and `..`?

Comment: @jimmij yeah I used the - P option of wget like this '- p ../foo/bar' and ended up finding '..'  In my current directory

Comment: Usually you remove such stuff with `rm -- './~'`, but in second case I doubt there are literal two dots, perhaps other unicode characters?

Comment: Hey @jimmij you are right. It's not `..` and it's not `~` either. They have a space before them. I used `ls -a` and ls `-l` but I really should've used `ls -al` sooner to spot that! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't create `..`; that entry always exists in every directory and refers to the parent directory.  You may want to check the parent directory for extra files.

To refer to `~`, you can put it in quotes to prevent the shell from expanding it: `"~"`.

Comment: Not really... `ls` alone shows me a `..` and `ls -a` gives me two. I think I've created one.

Comment: Wait... you are right! `ls -al` shows they are actually ` ..` and ` ~` with a space before them. Silly me! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have `mc` installed, use it

Answer (score 0):

I've used `ls` and `ls -a` but really should've used `ls -al` before asking the question.

`ls -al` shows

```
-rw-r--r--   1 Jing  staff  49630 27 Nov 11:02  
drwxr-xr-x   9 Jing  staff    306 19 Feb 09:32  ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 Jing  staff    102 19 Feb 09:46  ~
drwxr-xr-x   8 Jing  staff    272 19 Feb 10:09 .
drwxr-xr-x  15 Jing  staff    510 19 Feb 00:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x  10 Jing  staff    340 19 Feb 01:04 foo
-rw-r--r--   1 Jing  staff   2370 19 Feb 01:27 log
-rw-r--r--   1 Jing  staff    268 19 Feb 00:48 bar
```

As you can see `..` and `~` I was worrying about have a space before them. It's not that wget didn't work on `..` and `~`, it's just I added an extra space somehow. Using `rm -r ' ~'` and `rm -r ' ..'` worked.